# Is possible to do this from function.php

Tags: posts, images, single

In my single.php (my template Luna)
I have this code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>    

        <header class="page-entry-header" style="background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID) , 'max-control' ); ?>');">

    <?php endif; ?>
```

This show header with background image = featured image.

I want to remove the background (featured image - delete just in post) but not via single.php I want to remove via function.php, this is possible ?

¿How could I do this.?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: yes it is. If you meant to ask how to do it, please edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: your best bet is via css than a function, a single post will have a body class of .single so just use .single header {display:none;}

Doing it via the functions.php will require a lot more code as you will need to check if the code exists and the template is the right one etc.

Comment: If I do via css, the file is loaded in dom, I not want to do that.

Comment: You could probably do it via a somewhat complex filter but the CSS solution would be easiest.

Comment: @s_ha_dum no need for a complex filter, neither by using CSS ;-)

Comment: That is exactly the filter I was talking about @PieterGoosen :) The "complex" part is making sure it doesn't overly interfere. Your filter could still fire in unintended ways ;)

Comment: @s_ha_dum *Your filter could still fire in unintended ways*, not really. How you use and manipulate the parameters is the key. My example code is very basic, it is up to the OP to adjust to exact needs

Comment: It triggers on all thumbnail requests on a single post page, not just when that `header` bit fires, so yes it can fire in unintended ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you cannot just create a child theme and then simply copy the single template to your child theme and remove the code, but anyways, this is still a very interesting approach.

Regardless what have been said in comments using CSS to hide the thumbnail (*which I do not support as it will still show in the browser source*), there **are** better programmatic ideas to get rid of post thumbnails.

The best idea here would be to get the [`has_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) conditional return false only on single pages. To do this is super easy, we just need to follow the source code. Here is how it works

- [`has_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) uses [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/) which uses
- [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) which uses
- [`get_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/) which is filterable through
- the [`get_{$meta_type}_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_meta_type_metadata/) filter which holds our answer

The `{$meta_type}` part will be `post` as we will be using this filter to target posts, so our filter will be `get_post_metadata`.

So, in this filter, we need to set the first parameter `$value` to `false`. From the source

> Returning a non-null value will effectively short-circuit the function.

We would also only want to trigger this filter only for single posts and for post thumbnails, to will will check if we are on a single page and that our current `$meta_key` is `_thumbnail_id` which is the custom field key where the post thumbnail ID is stored.

With this all in mind, you can try the following

```
add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', function ( $value, $object_id, $meta_key )
{
    if (    is_single() // Make sure we are on a single post page
         && $meta_key === '_thumbnail_id' // Only run the filter for post thumbnails
    )
        return false; // Breaks the function which in turn return false for has_post_thumbnail()

    return $value;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, this works. But I have one problem with editor dreamweaver cs5, when I paste the code in function.php I get this alert: There is a syntax error on line 302. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Your dreamweaver version is too old and not yet compatible with closures that was introduced in PHP 5.3, that is why you get the error. You should upgrade your dreamweaver to the latest version ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Have a good day, I will see this of dreamweaver version.